Spring-Boot actuator endpoints in Angular
I get this error when i try to expose the health endpoint in my Angular app

default:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/actuator/health' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

while having this configurations to deal with Cors:
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods( "GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS") // Allowed HTTP methods
            .allowedHeaders("*") // Allowed headers
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedHeaders(allowedHeaders)
            .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);

    // Allow CORS for Actuator endpoints
    registry.addMapping("/actuator/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods(allowedMethods)
            .allowedHeaders(allowedHeaders)
            .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
}

my application.yml is like this:
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
      show-details: always
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  health:
    liveness-state:
      enabled: true
    readiness-state:
      enabled: true


Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please make sure to read the Markdown help as well as How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?. Also please review your posts after submitting to make sure they are readable - This one wasn't.  Helpful hint - You can hit the "Edit" link under anyone's post to see how they formatted.

Does the endpoints works with postman or similar?

Yes was using chrome, works fine there
